# how to show content in multiple classes with javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce, innerhtml

I am using tinymce for a textarea and i want to cout the characters inside of it.
Now i use this code:

```
<textarea class="tinymce" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<br />
<div class="character_count"></div>
<textarea class="tinymce" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<br />
<div class="character_count"></div>
<textarea class="tinymce" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<br />
<div class="character_count"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">      
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.tinymce',
        width: 400,
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                var count = CountCharacters();
                var x = $(".character_count");
                x[0].innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;
            });
        }
    });
   
    function CountCharacters() {
        var body = tinymce.activeEditor.getBody();
        var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
        return content.length;
    };      
</script>
```

This works fine, except the number of characters is displayed only in the first div (because of `x[0]`

is it possible to show, whatever textarea i am typing in, to display the characters in ever div `<div class="character_count"></div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, relace this line `x[0].innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;` with this

```js
x.each( function() { $(this).text("Characters: " + count); });
```

```js
const p = $("p")
$("input").on("input", function(e) {
  p.each(function() {
    $(this).text(e.target.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```